# Matrix Notation! (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

Suppose that we have a `NxM matrix`, where `N=rows` and `M=columns`.

How could I write nicely a summation for the last row of the columns of the matrix? I basically want to sum the columns of last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you denote the entry in row $i$ and column $j$ of a matrix $A$ as $a_{ij}$, then the sum of the entries (columns) in the $n$th row of $A$ is written as
$$\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{nj}=a_{n1}+a_{n2}+\cdots+a_{nm}.$$

The row is fixed ($n$) and the column goes from $1$ to $m$.